# Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'seasonal' was passed Error while trying decomposition in time series

Tags: python, time-series

I have a time series dataset with weather data.

I set as index the date column with the following code

```
data = data.set_index("date")
data
```

and it runs without any errors

Now I am trying decomposition with the following code

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
decomposition = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(data, model = 'additive', period = 2)
fig = decomposition.plot()
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [9.0, 5.0]
```

And I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'seasonal' was passed
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error, when I passed the entire data frame to seasonal_decompose()

Please check this link,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64300024

We should pass only one column and a DateTime index to seasonal_decompose.

df_seasonal = df.apply(lambda x: seasonal_decompose(x, model='additive').trend)